# Building a Hotel Reservation

Tags: mysql, sql

can anyone help me on how to get the available rooms from table1 to table2

here is the columns on my table1:

```
| id | roomTitle | description | maxOccupants | rate |
```

here is the column on my table2:

```
| id | arriveDate | departureDate | roomId | guestName |
```

my sql is (this will check if the users date request is available):

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE departureDate <= '...' OR arriveDate >= '...';
```

how to gather all available rooms from the table1 using the results on table2?

please correct me if I am wrong, i'm just a student trying to learn more, Thanks!

Comment: Please don't call your tables "table1" and "table2". It makes your schema very hard to understand..

Comment: I suggest you give meaningful names to stuff, even in quick exercises. Trying to fine tune queries from `table1` and `table2` makes it unnecessarily harder.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking "show me which rooms are available on a given date", you need something like:

```
select *
from   table1
where id not in
  (select roomid 
   from table2
   where   departureDate <= '$arrivalDate' 
   or arriveDate >= '$departdate')
```

Comment: Much better option.  What rooms ARE used and get list of rooms not found with the given date range.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `JOIN` using tabel1 id and table2 roomid